# Test if name is available in JSON and if not do other JSON request

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I was wondering what the best way is to test if a name exist in a JSON file. If the name is not present then load a different JSON file. I'm not having trouble testing if the name exist. I'm having trouble to load the new JSON file when the name doesn't exist.

Before people start down voting. I know that a simple if else doesn't work in this way but that's my question. So how do you set up some sort of 'if' 'else' function for testing if a name is present or not?

Let's say I want to test if "name" is present in the JSON file from 'url1'.

```
 $.getJSON(url1, function (json){ 

    var names = []; 

   if(json.hasOwnProperty('name')){

      // name is present in here so build some HTML

    } else {

      // name is not present in here so get a different JSON file and build other html
      $.getJSON(url2, function (json){

      }); 
    }
  });
```

The problem with this is that when 'name' doesn't exist in JSON from url1, the other JSON (from url2) don't get called.

To clarify some things I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/meules/AQzXL/4/)

Comment: what is problem with this?

Comment: Even `if (json.name) {` will work.

Comment: Add output of `console.log(json)`.

Comment: I've added a fiddle to clarify what I mean.

Comment: Your 'simple if-else' looks absolute OK, as mentioned - there need to be another problem. Use the debugger to set a breakpoint to the 'if' line and inspect the 'json'. Step to the else-tree, check url2 is ok, set another breakpoint inside the 2. success-handler and inspect 'json' there.

Comment: @fast: Ok thx for checking... helped me a lot already. I'm pretty new to javascript. I checked with 'console.log(json.hasOwnProperty('name'))'. This doesn't return 'false' when it should. I does return 'true' though. Could that be the problem? Does that mean I should use '!= undefined' etc?

Comment: Actually, i would strongly recommend to use an explicit flag value in your json to identify the different cases, e.g. json.responsetype = 1 for 1st variante, etc... Have a look at the json object, best use the Debugger (Strg+Shift+i or so..) and place some Breakpoints (if you don't know how, search for it, it will _really_ help!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use concurency.

```
function JsonGetter(listOfJsonUrls, name, i) {
    $.getJSON(listOfJsonUrls[i], function (json) {
            if (json.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
                // name is present in here so build some HTML
            } else {
                JsonGetter(listOfJsonUrls, name, i + 1)
            });
    }
}
```

call it like this:

```
JsonGetter(['url1','url2'], 'name', 0);
```

Comment: This looks promising ;) I gonna test this I'll let you know in a bit... thx!

Comment: Since the second response should be handled different to the first one, the original approach should be fine..

Comment: @fast: You mean my original approach or LIUFA's?

Comment: @JaapVermoolen i mean yours - LIUFAs is fine if the handling should not care if first or second call - how ever, you could at least check the 'i' value...

Comment: @fast: But that's my problem with my own code. The second json call isn't fired when the name is not present. See my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/meules/AQzXL/4/)

Comment: @JaapVermoolen see my comment to your orig question